# CONCATENATE in ArrayFormula's IF statement in Google Sheets not

Tags: google-sheets, row, concatenation, array-formulas

[Make Google Spreadsheet Formula Repeat Infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19039665/make-google-spreadsheet-formula-repeat-infinitely) helped me to expand my formula indefinitely and other StackExchange results helped me get to here:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((AF2:AF="")," ","L"&ROW(F2:F)&":AD"&ROW(F2:F)))

However, when I tell "L"&ROW(F2:F)&":AD"&ROW(F2:F) to CONCATENATE, every row gives a results as if it was CONCATENATE(L2:AD2).

I tried =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((AF2:AF="")," ",CONCATENATE("L"&ROW(F2:F)&":AD"&ROW(F2:F)))) and =ARRAYFORMULA(IF((AF2:AF="")," ",CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("L"&ROW(F2:F)&":AD"&ROW(F2:F))))) but neither are working.

I am trying to get each row to CONCATENATE(L2:AD2) then CONCATENATE(L3:AD3) then L4:AD4 and so on.

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To make more easy to explain and understand by using an example, assume that the source values are in the range `A2:C3`

Instead of using

```
ARRAYFORMULA(CONCATENATE(A2:C3))
```

use

```
ARRAYFORMULA({A2:A3&B2:B3&C2:C3})
```